# Modals.Are their job is only to add possibility or hypothetical?

Tags: modal-verbs

> 1. The children 'must have been playing' in the park since we gone shopping please find them out it's getting dark.
> 2. Just look at that car ! His father 'must have bought' it for him because he has been sad since her mother died.

My question is do modals have the ability to change the tense of the sentences?
Like 1 is in present perfect continuous and 2 is in present perfect.

They say we use modal+have+been for past events. We use present perfect also for past events but it has relevance at the time of speaking. I need in depth answer please if anyone can provide it.

Comment: An "in depth" answer would be very long.  Have you tried searching the internet?  For example, [this article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/English_modal_verbs#Usage_of_specific_verbs) should have all the depth you need.  If it's not sufficient, please add more detail to your answer to explain what you still don't understand.

Comment: *Must **have been** playing* versus *must **be** playing*. *Must* ***have bought*** versus *must* ***buy***. It's not the modal that's defining the tense here. Unless I'm misunderstanding your question.

Comment: No I searched the internet they say like this- These past (have+ past participle)modal verbs are all used hypothetically, to talk about things that didn't really happen in the past.

Comment: I know what(modals) they mean I'm asking like ' have been playing' is present perfect continuous and 'must have been playing' here 'must' just adding the certainty to the sentence also 'have bought' is present perfect and 'must have bought' here 'must' just adding certainty only without changing the tense?

Answer (score 1):

Most (maybe all) modals have two meanings, a *deontic* one about the real world (including social things like obligations), and an *epistemic* one about somebody's knowledge or expectation of things.

So *I must go* is deontic: I am stating that there is an obligation on me to go. But *He must be on his way* is epistemic: there is no obligation on him, the speaker has deduced, or is otherwise sure, that he is on his way.

When a modal is used with *have*, the meaning is very often epistemic: *He must have gone* cannot be deontic (we have to express the deontic meaning in other ways, such as "He had to go", or "He was obliged to go".

Other modals can take either meaning in the perfect, depending on context: *I should have seen it* is deontic, but *I think he should have got there now* is almost certainly epistemic.

So your examples are both epistemic "must".

But in answer to your main question, modals with "have" behave like past tenses, but not necessarily like (present or past) perfects: there is not necessarily any present relevance. "He should have seen it" can correspond to either "he saw it" or "he has seen it".

(Note also that epistemic *will* shows that *will* is indeed a modal, not a marker of "future tense": *He will have seen it by now* is epistemic and explicitly not future: it means something like "I conclude that he has seen it by now").

Comment: So according to your explanation the sentences should be like this:-1.The children 'must be' in the park since we gone shopping please find them out it's getting dark.
2.Just look at that car ! His father 'must buy' it for him because he has been sad since her mother died.

Comment: It's really confusing now because if I say modal+have+past participal sentences what would they mean really? Like you said "He should have seen it" can correspond to either "he saw it" or "he has seen it".

Comment: @Rocky, "He should have seen it" could mean "It was his duty/responsibility to see it" (deontic) or "I expect that he has seen it" (epistemic perfect) or "I expect that he saw it") (epistemic non-perfect). All are possible.

Comment: Sir you mean that in case of 'modal with have' we can only judge what the sentence mean by only in what context it is interpreted by the speaker present or in past is depend on situation. Like "the children 'must be' in the park since we gone shopping please find them out it's getting dark". This is the present context and sentence like "the children 'must be' in the park" this may be in the past context.

Comment: No, @Rocky. The present/past distinction is the one which _is_ required, but for many modals it is made not by using a past form of the verb, but by using the _have_ construction. "The children must be in the park" is present, and it is not idiomatic to use present verbs with _since_. So "The children must have been in the park since we went shopping".

Comment: I have few doubts: 1. The children must have been playing is a perfect continuous like sentence (describing duration)? only in this sentence because this sentence acting like a present situation not a past one(please find them out it's getting dark!). Can we use 'since' with present perfect and present perfect continuous? 3. Modal+have act like past and present depending on what context it has been said.

Comment: 1. Present perfect continuous usually comes right up to and includes the present (_I have been looking at it_ often means that I am still doing so, or that I have only just now stopped). Here it is a past situation extending into the present. 2. Yes, 3. Modal + have acts either like past or like perfect, so Modal + have + continuous acts like perfect continuous, and often extends into the present. On a different subject, you mean "find them". "Find out" is used of information, not of physical things (or people).